# Embedding TTF and using with g2d

Tags: java, graphics, fonts, drawstring

I'm trying to embed a TTF font and then use draw it with Grapics2D. I've been able to create the font, but I'm not exactly sure how to pass the font to setFont. I make a new font here, which throws no exceptions:

```
private Font pixel = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("font/amora.ttf"));
```

But I can't figure out how to draw it with setFont();

Here's my code:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Timer timer;
private Char Char;
private Font pixel = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("font/amora.ttf")); <<<--------

public Board() throws FontFormatException, IOException {

    addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
    setFocusable(true);
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    setDoubleBuffered(true);

    Char = new Char();

    timer = new Timer(5, this);
    timer.start();
}


public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.drawImage(Char.getImage(), Char.getX(), Char.getY(), this);
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.setFont( What goes here? );  // <------------
    g.drawString("Amora Engine rev25 (acetech09)", 10, 20);
    g.drawString(Char.getDebugStats(0), 10, 40);
    g.drawString(Char.getDebugStats(1), 10, 60);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    g.dispose();
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Char.move();
    repaint();  
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `g.setFont(/*What goes here?*/);` ... `pixel`?

Comment: One of pixel's methods, it seems like. I just can't seem to make sense of them though.

Comment: Actually, just pixel does work... but it makes the font precisely 1 pixel tall, so I didn't see it until just now. I presume one of these methods gives it a proper size.

Comment: Aand I solved my own question. pixel.deriveFont(12f) makes it that size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do...

```
g.setFont(pixel);
```

But you might have better sucess with

```
g.setFont(pixel.deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 36f));
```

Are variations of....

Also, don't dispose of a `Graphics` context you did not create...

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
/*...*/
// g.dispose();
```

Or

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
/*...*/
g.dispose();
```

I'd also be loathed to override the `paint` method.  Assuming you're using something like `JComponent` or `JPanel`, you should use `paintComponent`.  If you're rendering directly yo a top level container (like `JFrame`), then I wouldn't.  There are issues with double buffering and frame borders that won't make your life fun...

I'm also concerned about `new Timer(5, this)` - 5 milliseconds is close enough to 0 to make little difference.  You'd be better of with something like `40`, which should give you something like 25fps or `17` which will give you roughly 60fps...

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
g.setFont( this.pixel );
```

If this is not working, try:

1. Commenting out the `setFont` instruction.
2. Replacing `Font.createFont` with a reference to a Java standard font.

to rule out possible issues.